# Code to update GUI executes, but GUI never updates

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-interface

I have existing VB code that runs on a smart device (WindowsCE). I have edited the code to have a "simulation mode" where it compiles for windows instead of CE based on a preprocessor directive. In order to allow the user running the simulated device to understand what is going on without reading through log files, I am trying to add a UI. Currently, any code that is used to update the UI is executing but the changes never appear.

Here is what I have attempted thus far:

```
Public Module SomeDevice

#If __SIMULATE__ Then
    Private WithEvents _derp As New SimulatorGUI()
    Private _guiShown As Boolean = False
    Private _guiLoading As Boolean = False

    Private Sub handleShown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _derp.Shown
        _guiShown = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub handleLoading(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _derp.Load
        _guiLoading = True
    End Sub

#End If

   Public Sub Main()
   #If __SIMULATE__ Then
        Dim GUIThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(Sub() _derp.ShowDialog()) 
        'I have also tried System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(_derp))

        GUIThread.Name = "Simulator GUI"
        GUIThread.Start()

        While Not _guiLoaded OrElse Not _guiShown
            Thread.Sleep(0)
        End While

        SimulatorGUI.PutOnGUI("Loaded and shown")

 #End If
 'normal device functionality
   End Sub
End Module
```

In the SimulatorGUI class:

```
Public Class SimulatorGUI
    Public Sub PutOnGUI(ByVal message As String)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(Sub() PutOnGUI(message))
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Add(message)
            Debug.WriteLine("DOING STUFF: " + message)
            'ListBox1.Invalidate()
            ListBox1.Update()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I run this code, the Debug print shows up, the listbox internal collection shows that it contains the expected text, but the text never shows up on the GUI. Also, the "InvokeRequired" check never results in a call to Me.Invoke. If it matters, the rest of the device code runs entirely as expected. What is going wrong here?

Comment: FYI `Application.Run()` is the correct way of showing the first form since it also creates the UI message loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling the code from the instance you created.

Try changing the code to this:

```vb
'SimulatorGUI.PutOnGUI("Loaded and shown")
_derp.PutOnGUI("Loaded and shown")
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems so obvious now hah *rolls eyes*